# WSO2 WSB restart service background data is refreshed,How to modify?

Tags: wso2, esb

Every time the esb service is restarted, the logs previously running are refreshed. How do you keep the history?thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we deploy the ESB in a VM it will not clear the wso2carbon logs with a server restart. Could you please elaborate on the server deployment. If you are using a container-based deployment you will need to mount the logs to an external directory to avoid this.